# Errcode 13 error on delete of table

Tags: mysql

While attempting to drop a database in MySQL, an error message appears:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>    # 6 - Error on delete of './bedrock/grouprec.MYI' (Errcode: 13

I was logged in as root user with all privileges.

What's the cause of this error, and how can this be remedied?

Comment: bedrock is my database name...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which OS this MySQL instance is running on... Windows, Ubuntu, etc?

Do you have any anti-virus processes on the server?

Potentially a [process has this .myi file locked, thereby blocking the drop](http://beerpla.net/2010/01/05/how-to-fix-intermittent-mysql-errcode-13-errors-on-windows/).